# Conda: How can I update just the packages I specify in my command?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update a single package in my latest Anaconda installation (release date **2020-07-31**, `Ubuntu 20.04.1`), but lots of other package updates were suggested, including a few I don't necessarily want.

**How can I narrow down to updating only the packages I care about?**

## Spec

Python version: `3.8.3`

`Conda` version: `4.8.4`

## Problem Output

when I tried `conda update numpy`, `conda` either wants to update a lot of **other** packages, or complains that a specific version is pinned by `anaconda` package.

It doesn't need to be `numpy`, could be another package, like `scipy`. Below is what I got. Why are there so MANY packages? Can I not just get `numpy` and MOVE ON?

```
conda update numpy

# output below, why can't I just update numpy ONLY??
....

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _anaconda_depends  pkgs/main/linux-64::_anaconda_depends-2020.07-py38_0
  argon2-cffi        pkgs/main/linux-64::argon2-cffi-20.1.0-py38h7b6447c_1
  gettext            pkgs/main/linux-64::gettext-0.19.8.1-hd7bead4_3
  iniconfig          pkgs/main/noarch::iniconfig-1.0.1-py_0
  libiconv           pkgs/main/linux-64::libiconv-1.15-h63c8f33_5

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  asn1crypto         pkgs/main/linux-64::asn1crypto-1.3.0-~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::asn1crypto-1.4.0-py_0
  bitarray                             1.4.0-py38h7b6447c_0 --> 1.5.2-py38h7b6447c_0
  blosc                                   1.19.0-hd408876_0 --> 1.20.0-hd408876_0
  fribidi                                  1.0.9-h7b6447c_0 --> 1.0.10-h7b6447c_0
  fsspec                                         0.7.4-py_0 --> 0.8.0-py_0
  gstreamer                               1.14.0-hb31296c_0 --> 1.14.0-hb453b48_1
  ipykernel                            5.3.2-py38h5ca1d4c_0 --> 5.3.4-py38h5ca1d4c_0
  ld_impl_linux-64   pkgs/main::ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-h5~ --> conda-forge::ld_impl_linux-64-2.34-hc38a660_9
  lz4-c                                    1.9.2-he6710b0_0 --> 1.9.2-he6710b0_1
  notebook                                     6.0.3-py38_0 --> 6.1.1-py38_0
  numpy                               1.18.5-py38ha1c710e_0 --> 1.19.1-py38hbc911f0_0
  numpy-base                          1.18.5-py38hde5b4d6_0 --> 1.19.1-py38hfa32c7d_0
  pandas                               1.0.5-py38h0573a6f_0 --> 1.1.0-py38he6710b0_0
  pandoc                                             2.10-0 --> 2.10.1-0
  path.py                                          12.4.0-0 --> 12.5.0-0
  pip                                         20.1.1-py38_1 --> 20.2.2-py38_0
  pytest                                       5.4.3-py38_0 --> 6.0.1-py38_0
  python                 pkgs/main::python-3.8.3-hcff3b4d_2 --> conda-forge::python-3.8.5-h1103e12_5_cpython
  regex                             2020.6.8-py38h7b6447c_0 --> 2020.7.14-py38h7b6447c_0
  scipy                                1.5.0-py38h0b6359f_0 --> 1.5.2-py38h0b6359f_0
  setuptools                                  49.2.0-py38_0 --> 49.6.0-py38_0
  sphinx                                         3.1.2-py_0 --> 3.2.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-web~                             1.2.3-py_0 --> 1.2.4-py_0
  sqlite                                  3.32.3-h62c20be_0 --> 3.33.0-h62c20be_0
  tbb                                     2020.0-hfd86e86_0 --> 2020.1-hfd86e86_0
  tblib                                          1.6.0-py_0 --> 1.7.0-py_0
  urllib3                                       1.25.9-py_0 --> 1.25.10-py_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  glib                    pkgs/main::glib-2.65.0-h3eb4bd4_0 --> conda-forge::glib-2.65.0-h6f030ca_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  anaconda                                   2020.07-py38_0 --> custom-py38_1
  cffi                                1.14.0-py38he30daa8_1 --> 1.14.0-py38h2e261b9_0
  libffi                                     3.3-he6710b0_2 --> 3.2.1-hd88cf55_4
  zstd                                     1.4.5-h0b5b093_0 --> 1.4.5-h9ceee32_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

I did not like the fact that `python` was being updated to a `conda-forge` package (not that I have anything against `conda-forge` packages), since I did not ask for it.

Here is my `$HOME/.condarc` file:

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
```

Appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the dependencies update by disabling it in Anaconda. Details of this are explained [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#disable-updating-of-dependencies-update-dependencies)

You also need to pay attention to the official Note

> Conda still ensures that dependency specifications are satisfied.
> Thus, some dependencies may still be updated or, conversely, this may
> prevent packages given at the command line from being updated to their
> latest versions. You can always specify versions at the command line
> to force conda to install a given version, such as conda install
> numpy=1.9.3.

You need to create a file `.condarc` in the home directory of the environment. then add this line.

```
update_dependencies: False
```

Details are [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#creating-and-editing)

Thereafter, you can install the package.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, added this line as the last line in .condarc but it did not work. The docs you referred to here also says by default update_dependencies is set to False. Did I miss anything obvious here? Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you check it with it?
Disallow installation of specific packages (disallow)
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#disallow-installation-of-specific-packages-disallow

Put the list of packages name that you don't want to be installed or updated.

Comment: I ended up getting around this with `conda update --all`. Thanks

Comment: You solved the problem? Please let us know how did you solve it.

Comment: Just `conda update --all`, it seemed clean enough when I ran it, i guess some of the packages had been updated by the time I ran it this time.

Answer (score 1):

try `conda install pandas` for example, if you want to update pandas. It will check for the last version of the package, and if the package is already installed, it will be updated.